# Grant award Dates (US)

Tags: nsf, awards, research-proposal, nih

I've been in a conversation with a professor about hiring me as a potential postdoc. Recently he sent me an e-mail saying he would like to accept me to his team, but he can do this only if he can get a new grant.

As I understand the situation, his current grant is ending soon, and he hasn't been able to get new grants yet, but is still trying.

In general, when do US-based foundations announce their grant awards?  (I'd like to know so that I can ask him again on time whether he got a grant, so I don't lose the position that I kind of have right now.)

Comment: You do **not** "kind of have" a position right now.  You have a good lead on a position, but that's not the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

There's no fixed timeline. For example, the National Science Foundation has deadlines for proposal submission that are scattered around the year, and once a proposal has been submitted, it may take the NSF 3-9 months to decide. There are also numerous other funding agencies.

In other words, the only way for you to find out when that date *may* be is to communicate with the professor. He may have an idea when that may be, but the NSF doesn't set a fixed date when they will announce their grants -- that email may come on a random day and a random time.

Comment: Good answer. Also, the US Government has not had a proper budget for over a decade and is operating under a "continuing resolution". These, and the potential for retroactive budget cuts make it hard for NSF to administer grants.

Comment: That too. I'm sure that's one of the reasons why the NSF can't promise any deadlines.